# NodeJS - Cannot set headers after they are sent - Multiple Calls

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to write an app that find a city in a MongoDB collection and uses the latitude and longitude it returns to find all zip codes within a certain distance.  It seems to work, but the problem is that I'm getting an error that I can't set headers after they've already been sent.  However, I've separated the to routes into different requests I don't understand why I'm still getting this error.  What is the best way to make multiple calls to the API?

Here is my router in Node/Express:

```
// route to get city
app.get('/cities/:zip', function(req, res) {
    // use mongoose to get the city in the database
    console.log(req.params.zip);
    var query = City.find({"zip" : req.params.zip});
    query.exec(function(err, city) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        res.json(city);
    });
});

// route to find cities within 50 miles
app.get('/matches/:latMin/:latMax/:lonMin/:lonMax', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.latMin + req.params.latMax + req.params.lonMin + req.params.lonMax);
    var matches = City.find({latitude: {$gt: req.param.latMin, $lt:req.params.latMax }, longitude : {$gt :req.param.lonMin, $lt : req.param.lonMax}});
    matches.exec(function(err, match){
        if(err)
            res.send(err);
        console.log(match);
        res.json(match);
    });     
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./public/views/index.html'); // load our public/index.html file
});
```

Here is my Angular Controller

```
$scope.update = function (zip) {
    City.get({zip : zip}).success(function(response){
        $scope.weather = response
    }).then(function(response){
        $scope.weather = response.data;
    })

    if(zip.length = 5){
        $http.jsonp('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip='+ zip +',us&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&units=imperial').success(function(data){
            $scope.data=data;
        });


        var box = getBoundingBox([$scope.weather[0].latitude, $scope.weather[0].longitude], 50);
        City.matches(box[1], box[3], box[0], box[2]).success(function(response){
            $scope.matches = response
        }).then(function(response){
            $scope.matches = response.data;
            console.log($scope.matches);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Did you try changing `res.send(err);` to `return res.send(err);` ? Also on an unrelated note, your angular code has `zip.length = 5` instead of `zip.length === 5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.send` does not return; the call continues to `res.json`. And please use braces. Please. Maybe they don't look cool or whatever. Just use them.

```
if (err) { handleError(res, err); return; }
res.status(200).json(city);
```

Further down, keeping things DRY:

```
function handleError(res, err) {
  res.status(500).json(err);
}
```

Comment: I don't actually think you want to return those values as the calling function is not expecting a return value.  Don't you just want an empty `return;` statement after the call to `handleError(res, err);`?

Comment: "Not expecting" isn't the same as "doesn't care".